# Why is the hamburger button in my navbar not working?

Tags: html, css, flask

I am new to HTML and Flask. I am trying to create a navbar, but I don't know why the hamburger button isn't working. It looks like when I put the window smaller, the hamburger button appears, but it doesn't work when I click it. It doesn't show the items like "Login" "Home" or "Sign Up".

```css
 /*Anything related to color with be put in these css file */

 /*body, paragraphs, etc*/
 * {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Genos', sans-serif;

}
/*backgroud color*/
 body{
background-color:  #beeaa9 !important;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color:white;
 }
/*-Navbar color*/
.bg-custom-1{

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#5ae958 35%, #58e9af 100%) !important;
   
}

/*fa-bars color
.navbar .fas{

    color: rgb(30, 47, 47)!important;
    font-size: 26px;

} 
*/
/*margin-right, size-font*/
.navbar-nav{
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*needs space between the buttoms*/
}
.bg-custom-1 .navbar-toggler{
    padding-right: 20px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.united.css') }}">     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
        <title>Bank App Web</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

        <div class="header">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-custom-1">
                    <a class=navbar-brand href=""><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}"  > </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>       
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item"> 
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main') }}">Home </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" >
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('first') }}">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('first') }}">Sign Up</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        </div>
        
    

    </body>

        
</html>
```

I put the HTML and CSS files here! I don't know why is not appearing. I would like to know what I am missing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap requires its JavaScript plugin to function ([documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#js));

Include it in your page:

```css
 /*Anything related to color with be put in these css file */

 /*body, paragraphs, etc*/
 * {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Genos', sans-serif;

}
/*backgroud color*/
 body{
background-color:  #beeaa9 !important;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color:white;
 }
/*-Navbar color*/
.bg-custom-1{

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#5ae958 35%, #58e9af 100%) !important;
   
}

/*fa-bars color
.navbar .fas{

    color: rgb(30, 47, 47)!important;
    font-size: 26px;

} 
*/
/*margin-right, size-font*/
.navbar-nav{
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*needs space between the buttoms*/
}
.bg-custom-1 .navbar-toggler{
    padding-right: 20px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- include this -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.united.css') }}">    
 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
        <title>Bank App Web</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

        <div class="header">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-custom-1">
                    <a class=navbar-brand href=""><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}"  > </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>       
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item"> 
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main') }}">Home </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" >
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('first') }}">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('first') }}">Sign Up</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        </div>
        
    

    </body>

        
</html>
```

(You also have an additional closing html tag for your button (`</button>`) before the contained `<span>` element. Remove it)